# what is the difference between שלל, ביזה, and חרם?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash, army-military-war

We know that there are no true synonyms in the Torah. What does each of these connote? (to pass the test here - i googled and did not find anything)

Comment: You left out מלקוח

Answer (score 3):

"Cherem" implies that it is "off limits" from the general population; it will belong either to the kohanim, the Temple, Hashem, sacrificed, burned, something like that -- the Average Joe isn't going to get anything out of it.

As for the other two, check out [Rashi, Bamidbar 31:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.31.11?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=en)

שלל. הֵן מִטַּלְטְלִין שֶׁל מַלְבּוּשׁ וְתַכְשִׁיטִין:
בז. הוּא בִזַּת מִטַּלְטְלִין שֶׁאֵינָם תַּכְשִׁיט:

*Shalal* is clothing/jewelry; *baz* is any other (non-human, non-animal) object.